# converting hls livestream to rtmp

Tags: c++, python-3.x, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, rtmp

i'm new to ffmpeg

### Is it possible to convert hls livestream into rtmp with video resize and rotate without re-encoding

eg:

[hls](https://manifest.googlevideo.com/api/manifest/hls_variant/expire/1627905781/ei/lYoHYffiFvKHssUPpKqZiAg/ip/2402%3A3a80%3A1903%3Ace1b%3A%3A2/id/fzLm3Lvnxl8.2/source/yt_live_broadcast/requiressl/yes/hfr/1/playlist_duration/30/manifest_duration/30/maudio/1/vprv/1/go/1/nvgoi/1/keepalive/yes/fexp/24001373%2C24007246/dover/11/itag/0/playlist_type/DVR/sparams/expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Chfr%2Cplaylist_duration%2Cmanifest_duration%2Cmaudio%2Cvprv%2Cgo%2Citag%2Cplaylist_type/sig/AOq0QJ8wRQIhAKpCtWeKZNvpTt8OQ4vfbolbeWXEqhZTQTOW6Kw9LZH6AiAN5eL9fpRyy7dz6efFuAmLQa5M-H2An2nTAuPKlO1W7A%3D%3D/file/index.m3u8) into rtmp

is this even possible ?

sorry moderators for my bad grammer forgive me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Not possible

Resize (scaling) and rotation of the video requires using filters. [Filters require re-encoding](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Filtering).